# Tuespechkin cannot find wkhtmltox.dll

Tags: c#, .net, tuespechkin

Good morning,

I'm trying to generate pdf files with Tuespechkin, using html.
It works perfectly locally, however not in production.

```
    public static bool GeneratePDFFromHTMLPaysage(String full_path, String htmlContent, String baseUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            String content = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'><meta charset='UTF-8' name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'><title>Titre</title><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css'><script type='text/javascript' src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script></head><body><div class='container'>";

            content = content + htmlContent;
            content = content + "</div></body></html>";
            full_path = full_path + ".pdf";

            var document = new HtmlToPdfDocument
            {
                GlobalSettings =
                {
                    ProduceOutline = true,
                    PaperSize = System.Drawing.Printing.PaperKind.A4, // Implicit conversion to PechkinPaperSize
                    Margins =
                    {
                        All = 0,
                        Unit = Unit.Centimeters
                    },
                    Orientation = GlobalSettings.PaperOrientation.Landscape
                },
                Objects = {
                    new ObjectSettings { HtmlText = content }
                }
            };
            IConverter convert = new StandardConverter(
                new PdfToolset(
                    new Win64EmbeddedDeployment(
                        new TempFolderDeployment())));
            byte[] test = convert.Convert(document);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(full_path, test);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorManager.Log(e.Message + "\n" + e.InnerException + "\n" + e.StackTrace);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Basically, I tried to replace 64 bits with 32 bits, specified a static path for deployment as advised in documentation (doing so create a folder in which the missing DLL is placed, it has the same behavior in local than in production, but only work locally).

my application is a basic windows application, I simply copy files from Debug or Release folder to deploy it :

[image: the project]

as you can see, I included wkhtmltox.dll so it automaticaly deploy in the root folder of the project, but no results as well

**Summary : ** .NET 4 framework, windows application, trying to use Tuespechkin, had installated visual C++ 2013 on production trying to solve missing dll, and a lot of stuff with the code

Thanks for your attention, hoping for a solution

Answer (score 0):

Well, seems like my production server is just too old (windows server 2003), and that it might explain the problem